# Collections binary search on custom objects sorting issue

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Mytest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        searchperson();
    }

    private static void searchperson() {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            Person p = new Person(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i), i);
            personList.add(p);
        }
        Comparator<Person> sortComp = new Comparator<Person>() {
            public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
                return p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? 1 : -1;
            }
        };
        Comparator<Person> searchComp = new Comparator<Person>() {
            public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
                return String.valueOf(p1.getAge()).compareTo(String.valueOf(p2.getAge()));
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(personList, sortComp);
        Person p = new Person("2", "2", 2);
        int indx = Collections.binarySearch(personList, p, searchComp);
        System.out.println("index is:" + indx);
    }
}

class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

**This prints index is:1 which is expected.** 
But when I slightly change the sorting logic i.e) instead of `p1.getAge() > p2.getAge()` i just change it to `p1.getAge() < p2.getAge()`

```
Comparator<Person> sortComp = new Comparator<Person>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

**The binary search returns -1.**

**I am getting index is:-1**

I am not able to understand what the program returns -1 when I reverse the sorting. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Binary Search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) works on the premise that the collection has to be increasing with respect to how your `Comparator` is implemented. In other words, if you sort in ascending order with a `Comparator` then you have to search using the same `Comparator`, similarly if you reverse your `Comparator` then your collection has to be sorted in reverse order. So in your case:

```
Collections.sort(personList, sortComp); // Collection is sorted in ascending order (p1 > p2)
Person p = new Person("2", "2", 2);
int indx = Collections.binarySearch(personList, p, searchComp); // Search with (p1 > p2)
System.out.println("index is:" + indx);
```

You are sorting the collection in ascending order (e.g. p1 > p2) and then using the same comparator to search and thus it works. The moment you reverse your sorting, now the search is going to halve the collection and look for higher values in the upper half. Since the collection is in reverse order, it won't find any and return -1.

On a side note, when implementing `compare(a,b)` the function needs to return:

- a value less than 0 if a < b
- a value equal to 0 if a == b
- a value greater than zero if a > b

Thus instead of `p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? 1 : -1;`, you could do  `p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();`

If you are using **Java8+** you could simplify your `searchPerson` method to:

```
private static void searchperson() {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        Person p = new Person(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i), i);
        personList.add(p);
    }
    Collections.sort(personList, Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
    Person p = new Person("2", "2", 2);
    int indx = Collections.binarySearch(personList, p, Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
    System.out.println("index is:" + indx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Javadoc for binarySearch():

> *" The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the sort(List, Comparator) method), prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:**
>      *the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, **((insertion point) - 1)**. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the **index of the first element greater than the key**, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.*

Becuase your list is sorted in descending order once you update the Comparator, the search algorithm is 'searching' in the wrong direction:

*Pseudo*
1) Search "Lands" on "3"
2) Evaluates 2 compareTo 3
3) Moves search scope to left half of the list (expecting smaller numbers to be to the left of 3).
4) Search "Lands" on "4"
5) Evaluates 2 compareTo 4
6) Undefined result, list appears to be unordered because a larger number was found to the left of the original number.

Once this happens, binarySearch is behaving as though the element didn't exist in the list at all. In which case, it will return (-(insertion point) - 1). Insertion point here would be defined as index 0, because the first found value greater than the searched key, is "5" @ index 0:

```
index = (-(0) - 1)    
index = 0 - 1  
index = -1
```